# imshow function doesn't update image

Tags: c++, opencv

The below code captures the given video and outputs the frames using imshow() function **only when the statement calling the function detectMultiScale() is commented**. Is it only to me? If no, then why so?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main() {

    VideoCapture cap("test.mp4");

    cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640);
    cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480);

    if (!cap.isOpened()) {
        cout << "\nCould not open video file\n";
        return -1;    
    }

    Mat img;
    HOGDescriptor hog;
    hog.setSVMDetector(HOGDescriptor::getDefaultPeopleDetector());

    namedWindow("video capture", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

    while (true) {

        cap >> img;
        if (!img.data)
            continue;

        vector<Rect> found, found_filtered;
        // hog.detectMultiScale(img, found, 0, Size(4, 4), Size(8, 8), 1.05, 2);    

        imshow("video capture", img);
        waitKey(30);

    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: So, what does `found` output when the detectMultiScale is uncommented?

Comment: "outputs the frames using imshow() function only" -- How did you arrive to that conclusion? The function runs every time, what is it drawing? Could it perhaps be that the `detectMultiScale` function has a side effect and modifies the source image? It wouldn't be unprecedented, `findContours` behaves similarly. Try calling `detectMultiScale` with a deep copy of the input image.

Comment: @RachelL The variable 'found' is irrelevant to the rest of the code. Sorry for including it

Comment: @DanMašek Only the first frame is displayed when the commented line is uncommented. Else, the code runs fine and displays all the frames.

Comment: @Yashwanth OK, so what if you change the first parameter of `detectMultiScale` to `img.clone()`?

Comment: @DanMašek Tried it. The same thing was happening. Only the first frame is appearing.  Anyway, thanks for your advice. I doubt if this is happening only to me or everyone.

Comment: @Yashwanth Is that `continue` intentional? Shouldn't it be `break`, so that the loop actually terminates? Or at least add some message into that `if` statement, so you know when it failed to acquire a frame. I think it reaches the end of the video and then gets stuck in an infinite loop without you even knowing...